# Why do the two codes below generate different outputs?

Tags: python

```
a = [b'food']
b= list(b'food')
```

Output

```
a = [b'food']; b = [102, 111, 111, 100]
```

Comment: The distinction here is that `[b'food']` is a list containing a single element, which is a `bytes` object, while `list(b'food')` takes an iterable and makes a list out of it.  Since a `bytes` object is an iterable, `list` makes a list of the elements in the iterable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`list(...)` takes an iterable as parameter. `b'food'` is of type `bytes`,
and so `list(...)` creates a list from the bytes in it (`b'f'`, `b'o'`, ...).

The equivalent of `[b'food']` using `list(...)` would be:

```
b = list((b'food',))
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `list()` take iterable items as parameters and unpack them.

```
list("123") => ["1", "2", "3"]
```

Answer (score 0):

The first one creates a list with one element (`b'food'`).

Meanwhile the `list` function will convert a given iterable object to a list with a copy of its elements. So it creates a list with the binary representation of each letter of `'food'`.